# Download gmail attachment and save it to sd card in android

Tags: android, download, gmail, attachment

I have list of all gmail attachment now i need to download selected attachments and save it to sd card after user click on download button.

I have done it with below code but it is taking to much time to download.

Any one has done in better way kindly help me.

Below is my code.

Open connection and fetch all attachments and display in listView.

```
private Message[] emails;
ArrayList<ModelAttachment> attachment = new ArrayList<>();
Store store.connect("pop.gmail.com", "userName", "Password");

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
            emails = msgs;
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                Message message = msgs[j];
                String contentType = message.getContentType();
                Log.v("j", String.valueOf(j));

                String messageContent = "";
                Multipart multiPart;
                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                    multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                    for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
                        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
                        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                            // this part is attachment
                            ModelAttachment model = new ModelAttachment();
                            model.setName(part.getFileName().toString());
                            attachment.add(model);

                        } else {
                            // this part may be the message content
                            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                        }
                    }
                    if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                        attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                    }
```

When user click on download button below code will be executed.

```
 for (int k = 0; k < attachment.size(); k++) {
            if (attachment.get(k).isSelected()) {
                String fileName = null;
                try {
                    for (int j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
                        Message message = emails[j];
                        String contentType = message.getContentType();
                        if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                            for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
                                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
                                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                                    if (part.getFileName().equals(attachment.get(k).getName()))
                                        part.saveFile("sdCardPath" + File.separator + part.getFileName());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the model

```
public class ModelAttachment {

Object name;
boolean isSelected;

public Object getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(Object name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}}
```

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: i have tried using MimeBody part class but it is taking to much time.

Comment: please post your code otherwise people cant help you.

Comment: @AkashPatel I have added my code if you have any idea kindly help me